# Elasticsearch Synonyme are case sensitive

Tags: elasticsearch

I'd like to use synonyms with ES7.

I have:

> Synonyms:
> angularjs, angular.js, angular js

My expectation:

> Query: angularjs
> Match: angular.js

> Query 2: Angularjs
> Match: angular.js

Problem:

> Query: angularjs
> Match: angular.js

Query 2: Angularjs
Match: 0 hit

I use a filter

```
            filter:
              synonym:
                type: synonym
                #ignore_case: true
                lenient: true
                synonyms_path: synonym.txt
```

And I have an analyzer:

```
              synonym_analyzer:
                tokenizer: 'standard'
                ignore_case: true
                filter: [ lowercase, trim, asciifolding, elision, synonym ]
```

Why have I a different result with or without uppercase in my query? If my query doesn't have a synonym, it works perfectly.

How can I debug that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion works match angular.js for query angularjs and Angularjs:

Mapping

```
PUT idx_synonyms
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "language": {
        "type": "text",
        "analyzer": "standard",
        "search_analyzer": "synonym"
      }
    }
  },
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "analyzer": {
          "synonym": {
            "tokenizer": "standard",
            "filter": [
              "lowercase",
              "trim",
              "asciifolding",
              "elision",
              "synonym"
            ]
          }
        },
        "filter": {
          "synonym": {
            "type": "synonym",
            "synonyms": [
              "angularjs, angular.js, angular js"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Data

```
POST idx_synonyms/_doc
{
  "language": "angular.js"
}
```

Query:

```
GET idx_synonyms/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "language": {
        "query": "angularjs"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced with the same issue and I use **two analyzers** per **field**.

The first analyzer is the `search_analyzer` and the second analyzer is the `analyzer`.

When you send the search request the first analyzer will make your search pattern **lowercase** and will check your synonym table.

### Here is an example for you:

```
PUT test_index_with_two_analyzer
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "productname": {
        "type": "text",
        "fields": {
          "keyword": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "ignore_above": 256
          }
        },
        "analyzer": "word_delimiter_graph",
        "search_analyzer": "synonym_analyzer"
      }
    }
  },
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "analysis": {
        "filter": {
          "synonym": {
            "type": "synonym",
            "synonyms_path": "synonyms.txt"
          },
          "autocomplete_filter": {
            "type": "edge_ngram",
            "min_gram": "2",
            "max_gram": "20"
          }
        },
        "analyzer": {
          "synonym_analyzer": {
            "filter": [
              "lowercase",
              "synonym"
            ],
            "tokenizer": "whitespace"
          },
          "word_delimiter_graph": {
            "filter": [
              "word_delimiter_graph",
              "lowercase"
            ],
            "tokenizer": "keyword"
          },
          "autocomplete_analyzer": {
            "filter": [
              "lowercase",
              "kstem",
              "word_delimiter_graph",
              "autocomplete_filter"
            ],
            "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "standard"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-analyzer.html